# Performing a single switch-case

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this button and the working Switch instruction. The problem is that when I click on the case called "Koala" 2 actions take place when I only want one of them. How can I fix this?

```
private void KinectTileButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (KinectTileButton)e.Source;
    switch (button.Label.ToString())
    {
        case "Koala2":
            KinectTileButton_Click_1(sender, e);

            break;

    }
    var wineModel = button.Tag as WineModel;
    var selectionDisplay = new SelectionDisplay(wineModel);
    this.kinectRegionGrid.Children.Add(selectionDisplay);

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Why not just use an if statement? Doesn't make much sense to have a switch/case statement when you only test for one case. What are you expecting to happen? What happens?

Comment: Agreed with @SavannaKing, also, what do you mean "2 actions take place"? I don't understand what you expect to happen and what is actually happening.

Comment: What "2 actions" take place?  Your question doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you just don't want the actions following your test to execute :

so you may just add a return in your test.

A break won't help you to go "out of method", it's just for the switch.

```
private void KinectTileButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (KinectTileButton)e.Source;
    if(button.Label.ToString() == "Koala2")
    {
            KinectTileButton_Click_1(sender, e);
            return;//get out of this method.
    }
    var wineModel = button.Tag as WineModel;
    var selectionDisplay = new SelectionDisplay(wineModel);
    this.kinectRegionGrid.Children.Add(selectionDisplay);

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

or using an if /else

```
private void KinectTileButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = (KinectTileButton)e.Source;
        if(button.Label.ToString() == "Koala2")
                KinectTileButton_Click_1(sender, e);
        else  
        {
            var wineModel = button.Tag as WineModel;
            var selectionDisplay = new SelectionDisplay(wineModel);
            this.kinectRegionGrid.Children.Add(selectionDisplay);
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

by the way, it would be probably cleaner to do (well, I like small methods)

```
private void KinectTileButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (KinectTileButton)e.Source;
    if(button.Label.ToString() == "Koala2")
       Method1(<somearguments>);
    else
       Method2(button.Tag as WineModel);

    e.Handled = true;//if it must happen for all label values.
}

public void Method1(<some parameters>) {
  //DoSomething
}

public void Method2(WineModel wineModel) {
  var selectionDisplay = new SelectionDisplay(wineModel);
    this.kinectRegionGrid.Children.Add(selectionDisplay);
}
```

Comment: Even better, put an else around the rest of the function (no early return)

Comment: @LordTakkera sure, wanted to show an example "looking like the break", but you're right.